# django easy_pdf utf-8 characters

Tags: python, django

I've installed easy_pdf http://django-easy-pdf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html. I don't know is it installed properly. Some UTF-8 chars (łóżź) rendered not right. My template is:

```
{% extends "easy_pdf/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <div id="content">
        łóżąćęłń
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

and view:

```
class HelloPDFView(PDFTemplateView):
    template_name = "rhymes.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        return super(HelloPDFView, self).get_context_data(pagesize="A4", title="PDF", **kwargs)
```

Comment: Never used it. An idea (may not be a good one)... Had a look at [this link](http://django-easy-pdf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html). What if you use a font that supports those characters?

Comment: @strz Did you ever get this working and if so how?